# Troubles installing 'agricolae' package in R

Tags: r, installation, package

I am attempting to utilize the `HSD.test()` function found in the `agricolae` package but can't seem to install it correctly. I get the following error message:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘agricolae’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
> namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.0 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.10 is required
> In addition: Warning message:
> package ‘agricolae’ was built under R version 3.6.2

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your `>R.version` ?, from messages, seems you'll want to upgrade `rlang` (re-install, i.e., in a new session install.packages('rlang', dependencies = TRUE)`, though if you are still on R 3.6.2, you might be better off upgrading R to 4.2 altogether.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.